# Prove that exists ϵ>0 sucht that S∩C∩B((0,0,0),ϵ)=(0,0,0)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Please help me, I can't do it.

We have $S=$ { $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 ; f(x,y,z)=0$}, where $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $f(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)$ and $\nabla f(0,0,0)=(0,0,1)$.

$C=$ { $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 ; z\geq \sqrt(x^2+y^2)$}.

Prove that exists $\epsilon > 0$ sucht that $S \cap C \cap B((0,0,0), \epsilon) = {(0,0,0)}$

I can't find the way to do this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is not such an $\epsilon$. Then there is a sequence $x_n$ converging to $0$ in $C$ with $f(x_n)=0$. By Intermediate value theorem we can find a sequence $\tilde{x}_n$ with $\Vert \tilde{x}_n \Vert \le \Vert x_n \Vert$ such that $\langle \nabla f(\tilde{x}_n) , x_n \rangle =0$.

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable $\nabla f(\tilde{x}_n)$ converges to $(0,0,1)$. So we can choose an $N$ such that  $\Vert \nabla f(\tilde{x}_n)- (0,0,1) \Vert < \varepsilon <1/2$.

Let $p_{12}$ be the projection on the first two components and $p_3$ be the projection on the third component, then
$$ \langle \nabla f(\tilde{x}_n) , x_n \rangle = \langle p_{12} (\nabla f(\tilde{x}_n)) , p_{12} (x_n) \rangle +p_3( \nabla f(\tilde{x}_n) ) \cdot p_3( x_n ) . $$

But by Cauchy Schwartz
$$ \langle p_{12} (\nabla f(\tilde{x}_n)) , p_{12} (x_n) \rangle \le \varepsilon \cdot \Vert p_{12}(x_n) \Vert \le \varepsilon \cdot p_{3}(x_n) $$
which contradicts $\langle \nabla f(\tilde{x}_n) , x_n \rangle =0$ since
$$ p_3( \nabla f(\tilde{x}_n) ) \cdot p_3( x_n ) \ge (1-\varepsilon) \cdot p_3( x_n ) .$$